# Algolia Instant search default order by state (`live`, 'published', 'draft')

Tags: algolia, instantsearch.js, instantsearch, react-instantsearch

I'm trying to fetch Algolia results in particular order, hits have state column, and state values can be `live/published/draft`

**Data in algolia**

```
{ name: Post1, state: draft},
{ name: Post2, state: published},
{ name: Post3, state: live}
```

**Expected Result**

Default order should be, first live then published and then show draft

```
{ name: Post3, state: live},
{ name: Post2, state: published},
{ name: Post1, state: draft}
```

Comment: sort the hits array using js sort?

Comment: @cmgchess Algolia should return hits in this order, don't want to use external js logic to sort this.

Comment: all i could find about sort in algolia is for numeric fields

Answer (score 0):

Algolia doesn't support sorting by an enumerated type like this. Instead, in search, it is more common to use the state as a facet and allow users to filter results based on the enumerated value.

You could simulate the enumerated sort by performing a [multi-index query](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-methods/multiple-queries/?client=javascript) with three separate queries to the same index with each of the state values as a filter, then display the results for each state.